# Getters and Setters as functions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I know in C++ that I should use a GET and a SET function to access my variables from other places. However in C# this seems to be a property. So my question is should I not use functions for my GET and SET and instead use the c# style in Unity3d?

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Highest tempruture during the different weathers. 
/// </summary>
[SerializeField]
protected float _fHighestTemp;

/// <summary>
/// This is our GET function for reading the value. 
/// </summary>
public float GetHighestTemp() { return _fHighestTemp; }

/// <summary>
/// This is our SET function this one we use to set the highest temprature we could have during different weather. 
/// </summary>
public void SetHighestTemp(float SetHighestTemp) { _fHighestTemp = SetHighestTemp; }
```

Is there any downside to using it with functions? (More memory heavy, or anything else) And could if not, why is it better to use the c# way where its properties instead?

Sorry for the noob question but I really would like to know before I go into a Unity project the wrong way and have to go back and redo it all.

Comment: Literally, there is nothing wrong with functions. But it takes so much more typing. Compare your 3 lines with only one to simple `public float HighestTemp {get; set;}`! And in terms of unity, I assume, the properties are linked to the UI while as functions - no, but I`m not sure about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recent version of C#, I cant remember which, getters and setters for properties have as shortcut an automatically implemented properties syntax.

**This**

```
protected int MyInt{get;set;}
```

**Is equivalent to**

```
protected int _MyInt;
protected int GetMyInt(){return _MyInt;}
protected void SetMyInt(int value){_MyInt=value;}
```

**This**

```
private int MyInt{get;set;}
```

**Is equivalent to**

```
private int _MyInt;
private int GetMyInt(){return _MyInt;}
private void SetMyInt(int value){_MyInt=value;}
```

The following is also valid:

```
public int MyInt{get;}
public int MyInt2{set;}
public int MyInt3{get;set myMethod(value);}
public int MyInt4{get{return myMethod();}}
```

Comment: This is also very useful: public int MyInt { get; private set; }

Answer (score 0):

Properties are the idiomatic representation of accessors in C#, so yes, you should use them. You can implement your own property accessor methods or use the automatic properties.